# How to ignore captured exceptions in RX flows in Visual Studio Debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, system.reactive

I have code like this:

```
int Check(int value)
{
    if (value < 100)
        throw new Exception();
    return value;
}

var s = new Subject<int>();
s.Select(Check)
    .Retry()
    .Subscribe();
```

And when I call `s.OnNext(50);`, my debugger in Visual Studio stops on line `throw new Exception();` It's not very userful, because having exceptions is quite normail in my situation and I would like to have behavior like with using `try-catch` block, where captured exceptions doesn't stop debugging process.

Answer (score 0):

This is a debugger issue. The code is fine.

Try this:

```
void Main()
{
    var s = new Subject<int>();
        s.Select(Check)
            .Retry()
            .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

    s.OnNext(50);
    s.OnNext(500);
}

int Check(int value)
{
    if (value < 100)
        throw new Exception();
    return value;
}
```

You still get `500` so you need to change the debugger settings.